# How to sort dataframe by weekday in pyspark?

Tags: sorting, pyspark

My dataframe is generated as below:

[image]

I don't know why it is generated like that, seems randomly sorted, or no sorting at all.

I want to sort it by the normal weekday sequence, i.e. either starts with Monday or Sunday, or just let me indicate which day is the first day and the rest must remain the right order.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start the sorting earlier, maybe create an extra column to indicate the order, so the actual table would have three columns indeed: count, weekday, weekday_order